# Filter array of strings by string js

Tags: javascript

```
const myArray = ['Dart V', 'Skywalker L', 'Skywalker E'];
const myString = 'walk';
```

Needed to filter by **'walk'**.

**Want to get**:

```
const filteredArray = ['Skywalker L', 'Skywalker E'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const filteredArray = myArray.filter((item) => item.toLowerCase().indexOf('walk') !== -1);
```

Comment: `myArray.filter((item) => item.includes('walk'));` is even more concise